# How to compile R package that uses rJava

Tags: java, r, rstudio, rjava

I have [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) successfully installed, and I'm trying to compile a package that uses some Java code - in this case the [RHive](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHive/index.html) package.

If I'm in RStudio and I do "Clean & Rebuild" or "Build & Reload", the Java code never seems to get compiled.  I see this in the console:

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source RHive

* installing to library ‘/home/kwilliams/R-dev’
* installing *source* package ‘RHive’ ...
** package ‘RHive’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RHive)
```

but if I make changes to the Java code - syntax errors even - it doesn't seem to have any effect.  So clearly my configuration is wrong somewhere.

What am I supposed to do in a project's setup to tell it there's Java code that needs to get compiled?  Is there anything RStudio-specific I'll need to do too?

Comment: Not sure this will help, but it's a good idea to run `R CMD build` and then run `R CMD INSTALL pkg.tar.gz` to keep your source tree clean.

Comment: Actually I did try that, seems to have the same results.  Is there an RJava packaging manual somewhere I haven't found maybe?

Answer (score 1):

[Over on github](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/33), Simon clarified that the package author needs to take care of compilation separately and that there's no provision in the R build process to compile Java code.

If I can get back to this issue (at work) I might try to submit a doc patch that makes it clear that the java has to be compiled manually, and how one might go about it.